# Slow Community Performance

Tags: community

My entire Community is and has been slow.  We have mostly aura components.  Any tricks for speeding it up other than looking at individual component code?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using lightning communities

Generally, slow performance can be attributed to number of reasons

1. Too many components on a single page
2. Too many requests XHR,JS,CS files
3. Not optimized component code.
4. Blocking XHRs
5. Large images being loaded
6. Not using progressive loading in community.
7. DEBUG mode is ON

Please identify which pages are the slowest and use this extension by Salesforce to get insights about what is the cause of slow performance. It gives the rating in each area and sights about how can you improve.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-community-page/alkcnclapbnefkodhbkpifdkceldogka

This extension will cover most of the 6 points mentioned above. Once you have found the major blockers you should work on them starting with lowest rating.

Then you can look into optimizing the number of components on the page and if any of them have a deep hierarchy like one component extends another which in turn extends another.

If you have time then you can can also look towards porting Aura components to LWC slowly.